# с++: использование дружественного класса

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, дружественная-функция

Запутался в дружественных классах и функциях. Поясните мне, пожалуйста, где у меня в коде ошибка:

```
class CClass1;

class CClass2
{
    friend CClass1;

public:
    void mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x);
};

void CClass2::mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x)
{
    class1.set(x);
}

// -----------------

class CClass1
{
private:
    int m_x;

protected:
    void set(const int x);
};

void CClass1::set(const int x)
{
    m_x = x;
}
```

получаю сообщение:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2248   'CClass1::set': cannot access protected member declared in
>   class 'CClass1'   friend  d:\tmp\friend\friend.cpp    31
>
> Error (active)        function "CClass1::set" (declared at line 34) is
>   inaccessible  friend  d:\tmp\friend\friend.cpp    20

Я же указал, что класс `CClass1` является дружественным для `CClass2`. Почему это не сработало?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала надо перенести

```
void CClass2::mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x)
```

после объявления `CClass1` - чтоб компилятор знал, что это такое.

А дальше... Смотрите, я говорю - вы мой близкий друг, так что на правах друга я могу снимать деньги с вашего банковского счета и распивать пиво в компании вашей жены, пока вас нет дома. Что вы на это скажете? Что я самозванец, вы вообще меня первый раз в жизни видите. И совсем другое дело, если **вы** скажете, что я ваш друг, и вы мне все это позволяете, правда?

Ваш класс `CClass2` ведет себя как я в первом примере - говорит, что у него `CClass1` в друзьях и на этом основании лезет в его кошелек (к защищенному члену).

Для этого `CClass1` должен объявить другом `CClass2` и разрешить ему тем самым лезть в кошелек. Чувствуете разницу? Кто-то разрешает другу некоторые стрёмные действия. А не любой проходимец говорит, что вы его друг и беззастенчиво вами пользуется :)

Во как она выглядит в коде:

```
class CClass1;

class CClass2
{
public:
    void mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x);
};

// -----------------

class CClass1
{

    friend CClass2;

private:
    int m_x;

protected:
    void set(const int x);
};

void CClass1::set(const int x)
{
    m_x = x;
}

void CClass2::mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x)
{
    class1.set(x);
}
```

Comment: А по идее легко представить ситуацию, когда в обоих классах будут друзья объявлены - когда и тот и тот захотят пользоваться приватными членами и метода другого класса?

Comment: @Zhihar, Вы утверждаете или спрашиваете? :)

Comment: Вполне реально. Стоит ли? Дружба - она позволяет даже больше, чем наследование. Так сказать, сыну может быть не позволено то, что другу... :)

Answer (score 2):

У вас не в том классе friend зарегистрирован, исправил ваш код:

```
class CClass1;

class CClass2
{
public:
    void mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x);
};

// -----------------

class CClass1
{
    friend CClass2;
private:
    int m_x;

protected:
    void set(const int x);
};

void CClass2::mega_set(CClass1& class1, const int x)
{
    class1.set(x);
}

void CClass1::set(const int x)
{
    m_x = x;
}
```

Код компилируется: [тык](http://cpp.sh/8f4es)